# What is a working directory in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I created a Maven project and imported it in Intellij IDEA.

In a run configuration, there is a field "working directory", which points to the root of Maven project.

If I change this folder, it doesn't seem to affect anything. So what is it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the directory that is set as the Java `user.dir` system property. If you have any code that creates relative files or directories, it will be relative to this directory. So for a well designed application (i.e. resolves resources from the classpath and is configurable for output directories) this will not be a factor. There is also some importance to this value in maven projects, especially multi-module maven projects. This directory specifies the directory IDEA will read the POM from.

If you are unflamilar with what the Java `user.dir` is, there is some discussion available [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302988/trying-to-understand-on-what-user-dir-property-actually-means) and in the class level [Javadoc for the File class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html).

Comment: I have a testng project. My tests will run only if working directory = $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$. What is this $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ ? How do I find the full path stored in this variable ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` is an IntelliJ IDEA macro to represent the (IntelliJ IDEA) module's root directory. If you go to _File > project Structure_, click on "modules" on the left, and then select the module, and then select the "sources" tab it will show the root directory of the module.It's the top most path in the tree of directories.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to answer given by @Javaru if you want to update or view your working directory in IntelliJ IDEA go to:

Run | Edit Configurations | Configuration Tab | Working Directory

Answer (score 4):

From the IntellJ help [Run/Debug Configuration: Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-maven.html?utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=IC&utm_content=2017.1#parameters)

> Working directory  Specify the path to the Maven project file pom.xml.