# Unable to re-open java projects in IntelliJ - am I saving them correctly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java project that is written in IntelliJ and consists of several classes and the console, it's a rather basic project.

However, when I close it, I cannot reopen it, unless I do so through File -> Open Recent, which does re-open all the classes. But, if go through several different projects, this one is no longer in the Recents menu, and the only way I can get it back is to rebuild it from the .java files.

What am I doing wrong? I must be missing some basic, important step. Even something as basic as a single project file that I can re-open would be a helpful, because I have rebuilt this project 3 times.

(and yes I have read the Opening, Reopening and Closing Projects page in the documentation. There are no files with the extension *.ipr, .classpath, .project, or pom.xml, and if there are folders with the IJ icon then I have not found them anywhere near where I expect them to be).

Thanks,

Comment: "File" -> "Open" and selecting the project directory does not work?

Comment: Not enough info to debug your issue. A wild guess would be that the directory of the project doesn't have write permissions and as such, when IntelliJ opens the project it cannot write its project files to disk, which might explain why you can't "re-open" it.

Comment: Henry, it seems to work for some other projects, but not this one. Granted, it can be difficult enough to find the project directory with IntelliJ's unusual directory menu, but I think I have the right location for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a `.iml` file in your module directory - that is IntelliJ Idea module file. You need to open that file to open your module.

If all your modules are in a single working directory ( i.e. single project ) , usually `IntelliJ` opens all of modules by default.

is `.iml` file missing?

Here is a question on SO about working directory - [IntelliJ Idea Working Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838334/what-is-a-working-directory-in-intellij-idea)

You can also retry **importing** your module so your `.IML` gets recreated - in case it is corrupt or so.

Comment: There is a .iml file, but when I open it, it only opens that single file, and has only these contents:   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">  
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />  
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">  
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />  
    </content>  
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />  
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />  
  </component>  
</module>

Comment: so .iml itself gets opened in intellij? In my Windows system, if I choose .IML to be opened with IntelliJ Idea, module gets opened.

Comment: Also, your iml seems similar to mine so don't see any issue there.

Comment: Correct, it opens the .iml as though it's just a text file with xml info. It's the same effect as if I opened it in Notepad, just with IntelliJ.