# Confusion over current working directory in File’s getAbsolutePath method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The file’s getAbsolutePath has the tendency that if a relative path or just the file name is provided in the file constructor, then it will resolve the absolute path by prefixing the current working directory.

The definition of current working directory is the directory where we run our Java Program.
In my example, my java program resides inside  `D:\my-app\src\App.java`

When I do a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Then it should ideally print `D:\my-app\src`

But it is actually printing `D:\my-app`

Why is it so?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact statement how you compile and run your java application, including the directory where you have started the command.

Comment: I’m running Using IntelliJ

Comment: It may be where the code is executed

Comment: *"Why is it so?"* - because that's how you are running the program. Are you asking *how* to run your program with a different working directory?

Comment: The code is executed inside the directory D:\my-app\src mentioned above. So why it is not printing that directory ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a working directory in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838334/what-is-a-working-directory-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: @Sandy no, it is not. `src` is where your source code resides. IntelliJ uses the project's main folder as the working directory.

Comment: Well Partially, I agree with the answer, but according to the definition of the current working directory, the current working directory should be the one where my program is executed. My program is executed/running inside the src folder. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you start an application from IntelliJ, its working directory is set according to what's set in ["Working directory" in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html).

There, you can set the working directory to a fixed value such as `D:\my-app\src`. Another option is to use a [path variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html). The list of variables that are available apparently can depend on many things - open the dialog and see what's available. One option that I see is `$FileDir$` which I imagine would be the directory of the source code file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Intellij was actually causing the issue by implicitly setting the src folder as the source folder. I found it by going to the module setting within Intellij.
When I ran the same from a command prompt, the correct working directory i.e. `D:\my-app\src\` is selected.